# How to manage " " and ' ' when declare variable in javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a search box and user can put the search text to it. Example: book, 'book', "book". And in js file, a variable get value from search box.

```
var searchtext= "${searchtext}"; <br/>
```

This code is failed if user put "book" to search box.Because this time,

```
var searchtext= ""book"".
```

If I change

```
var searchtext= "${searchtext}";  to var searchtext= '${searchtext}';
```

This code is failed if user put 'book' to search box. Please help me, thanks !

Comment: What backend language is it?

Comment: You have to make sure that special characters like that are escaped.

Comment: If you do `var searchtext= ${searchtext}; ` without quotes, fails too ? as @dfsq says, which is the backend language ?

Comment: You can remove all quotes and then do the search! Something like this test.replace(/\"/g, "");

Comment: string.replace(new RegExp(""", 'g'), "'");

Comment: @Liαrεz: if without quotes, it is fail.I am using java code, get value from java class and put to jsp

Comment: @quocbaoPham Then please post the Java code that does that

Comment: @Dragondraikk: String inputKeyword = getSearchText();
  if (StringUtils.isBlank(inputKeyword)) {
   inputKeyword = (String) request.getAttribute("searchText");
  } else {
   inputKeyword = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(inputKeyword);
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can both replace `"` or `'` by a single quote `'`. Here's an example:

```
var str= '"book"'; 
str.replace(/["|']+/g, "'");
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjs3ebtm/)

Comment: what happen if user input 'book'. This time, str=' 'book' '

Comment: And it will be replace by 'book'

Comment: Now, var str= ' 'book' ', user will be announced the message : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier by browser

Comment: you must escape ' in this way: '\'book\''

Comment: Thanks, Radonirina. But I want to the input and output search text is the same result. EX : "book" => "book". The present: ''book" => 'book'

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for you if you dont allow user to insert special characters into search box.

```
$('searchBoxElement').bind('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: user can input special symbols.

Answer (score -1):

Quick dirty fix

```
str.replace(/["|']+/g, "'");
var searchtext= "${searchtext}";
```

Comment: that'll only replace the first occurrence of ~"" ~